# How to sort a .txt or .csv file (matlab)

Tags: matlab, sorting

I'm new to matlab. I have a large csv file that I can also make as a text file. This file consists of lines of integers and symbols such as -, :, and others. I want to be able to read each line of this file and sort it numerically. For example:

2000-01-08T16:47:32.200Z, -16.84, -173.93, 162.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT

I need to see the first 3 groups of numbers as the date and the T00:00:00 as the time of day, and then sort the lines from earliest to latest. Each line has the exact same format.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you expect to get a complete solution? Well you have to read in the lines, probably a vector or maybe even a cell array. Then you have to sort the by the column. That can give a vector with induces how to rearrange the vector/cell array with your lines. As every step is rather simple, you need to be more specific about what you tried and what went wron.

Comment: you want them sorted by date and then if they have the same date sorted by time? if you use `,`as seperation why is it  ....T16:47:32.200Z... ? shouldn't it say: ...32,200Z...?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution for your specific case:

```
my_data=importdata('test_1.txt');
tmp_data= cell(numel(my_data),7);
tmp_data(:,7) = my_data;
for k=1:numel(my_data)
    tmp_datapoint = my_data{k,1};
    tmp_year = str2double(tmp_datapoint(1:4));
    tmp_month = str2double(tmp_datapoint(6:7));
    tmp_day = str2double(tmp_datapoint(9:10));
    tmp_hour = str2double(tmp_datapoint(12:13));
    tmp_minute = str2double(tmp_datapoint(15:16));
    tmp_second = str2double(tmp_datapoint(18:19));    
    tmp_data(k,1:6) = {tmp_year,tmp_month, tmp_day, tmp_hour, tmp_minute, tmp_second};
end
tmp_data = sortrows(tmp_data, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
sorted_data = tmp_data(:,7);
```

Importdata saves your data e.g.

```
2000-01-08T16:47:32.200Z, -16.84, -173.93, 162.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
2000-01-04T19:47:32.200Z, -16.84, -193.93, 162.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
2000-01-08T16:47:35.200Z, -16.84, -173.93, 165.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
...
```

and at the end `sorted_data` contains your sorted data like:

```
2000-01-04T19:47:32.200Z, -16.84, -193.93, 162.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
2000-01-08T16:47:32.200Z, -16.84, -173.93, 162.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
2000-01-08T16:47:35.200Z, -16.84, -173.93, 165.7, kiloMETER, 6.7, MB, CMT
...
```

As a matter of fact your data is allways saved as a string inside a cell matrix. So if you got any problems with the adressing check those variable types.